# Removing duplicates from an unsorted array using set approach

Tags: c++

So the problem states that I have to input an array of unsorted elements containing duplicates and I decided to use sort. I am new to this and I don't understand the error

I'm trying to run it on GFG's IDE.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

int main() {
    //code
    int n,size,a;
    cin>>n;
    while(n--)
    {
        cin>>size;
        int a[size];
        set<int> s;
        for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
          {
              cin>>a;
              s.insert(a);
          }
          for(int i=s.begin();i!=s.end();i++)
            cout<<i<<" ";
    return 0;
}
```

Error message:

```
no match for 'operator>>' (operand types are 'std::istream {aka std::basic_istream<char>}' and 'int [size]')
            cin>>a;
```

Comment: Why do you need an array of numbers? Make `a` to be simple `int` and your problem will be solved.

Comment: commented out int a[size].

Comment: made it into int a;

Comment: why do you need n? number of array?

Comment: still gives an error

Comment: n was for the test cases sorry.

Comment: should have been more specific, my mistake

Comment: cannot convert 'std::set<int>::iterator {aka std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<int>}' to 'int' in initialization
        for(int i=s.begin();i!=s.end();i++)   -This is the new error

Comment: `for(int i=s.begin();i!=s.end();i++)
            cout<<i<<" ";` should be `for(auto i=s.begin();i!=s.end();i++)
            cout<<*i<<" ";`

Comment: It looks like you need [a good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). `begin()` return an *iterator* not an `int`.

Comment: Need to read up on how iterators work.

Comment: Unrelated to the source of your problem, but please also see [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h) and [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: Now that we've established that you are including `<bits/stdc++.h>`, let's explain [why that isn't always a good idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)

Comment: Or you could write this `for(int i : s) cout<<i<<" ";`. That's a *range-based for loop*, another thing to read up  on.

Comment: You have way too many errors

Comment: I shall read up o iterators. Yes. Thank you for your inputs. I actually do not understand how begin() works

Answer (score 1):

The source of the error you show is this line right here:

```
int main() {
   //...
       int a[size]; 
   // ...
}
```

`a` is an array now, which has no `operator>>()` overloaded for it for `std::istream`.

The solution is simple, just change this line:

```
cin>>a;
```

to this:

```
cin>>a[i];
```

Now, there should be no compiling problems, although a ton of bad practices still, which several answers and other comments and an answer has attempted to correct. I'll leave that to them.

The only thing I will warn you about is

```
int a;
some block {
   int a[size];
}
// try to use a:
a[i]; // bad
```

There are 2 variables named `a` in your program. Once the second a goes out of scope, it will destroy the array version of `a`, and use the regular `int a` instead. Just be wary of this.

P.S. Okay, so I will mention another one that seems unmentioned by others.

The following [is ill formed](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub), since it tries to use a variable-length array:

```
cin>>size;
int a[size];
```

Some compilers will support it, but technically, that is an ill-formed program. As a general rule, don't do it.

Comment: Thank you :) I shall do the needful